# WPF - Enable 2nd combobox on 1st combobox selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have two ComboBoxes, I want to enable the second ComboBox upon selection of First ComboBox. I have tried adding `IsEnabled` property but doesn't seem to work. The code I have tried is below.

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="siteComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,104,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Site}" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSite}"/>
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="planTypeComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,159,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding PlanType}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlanType}" 
     IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=siteComboBox}"/>
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? or Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DataTriggers. When the selected item is null the second ComboBox will be disabled

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="siteComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,104,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Site}" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSite}"/>
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="planTypeComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,159,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding PlanType}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlanType}">
     <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxe:ComboBoxEdit}">
             <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=siteComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                     <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Style>
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

**Edit** : If you are using implicit theme, the defined style must inherited from the theme style:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="siteComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,104,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Site}" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSite}"/>
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="planTypeComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,159,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding PlanType}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlanType}">
     <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxe:ComboBoxEdit}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type dxe:ComboBoxEdit}}">
             <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=siteComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                     <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Style>
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A `ComboBox` does not have an `IsChecked` property. So that binding isn't going to work.

You could set up another property like `IsSiteSelected` that returns true when `SelectedSite` is not null and bind to that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

For the second combo box set IsEnabled when SelectedIndex of first combo box is not -1
Or define a SelectionChanged event for first combo box and enable/disable second combo box in backend